# C++ sort n-dimension array across arbitrary dimension

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, iterator, std

I have n-dimension arrays of double values stored as vectors with last index-major, that have to be sorted w.r.t. a given dimension k. A classical strategy consists in first permuting dimensions k and 1 then sort i.e. with std::sort with respect to first index then permuting dimensions again. I was wondering how this strategy would compare (in terms of speed) to the use of a custom iterator.

For example, let us consider X a NxM array  2d, second index major, that has to be sorted with respect to second index. For a given row number i,  values to be sorted are X[i+N*j], j=0..M-1, and could be accessed and sorted by using a custom iterator taking into account that values are not consecutive in memory.

How would compare the respective cost (in terms of e.g. cache, page faults, ...) of accessing non-consecutive values while sorting (with the custom iterator) w.r.t. the cost of the same type of access, but only during the two permutations ?

Comment: If you want to ask about cache behavior, you need to specify sizes. Are we talking about a 4x4x4x4 vector or a 1000x1000x1000? Performance of the sort on a custom iterator will probably be positively awful if each element to be sorted is in a different page (possibly _much_ worse if the cache lines align badly and evict each other due to identical page offsets). None of this might matter if all your data fits into a page or even a single cache line.

Comment: Yes, this is for potentially big arrays, typically N x M x 3 (RGB images). I thought that permuting would generate the same amount of cache/page faults.

Comment: Well, permuting twice has different asymptotic complexity than sorting (albeit not much). You might have good success by extracting, sorting (out-of-place) and then updating each slice one after the other. But I still don't understand: In an `N x M x 3` image, do you want to sort each row (or column, or color triplet)? Or do you want to sort each color triplet column (or color triplet row, or color "slice")? The 2D case doesn't illustrate that difference.

Comment: Concerning the `N x M x 3` case: when you want to build an histogram of each component, which is a typical task in image processing, then you have to sort the array across to the third dimension.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Which part of `for (auto value : data) histogram[getBin(value)]++;` requires sorting? Maybe you need to find min and max first (that just requires a single pass, not sorting), but ordinarily each component is just a byte and you go in with e.g. 256 bins...

Comment: Well, the image processing was not a good example. I am just trying to find a way to efficiently implement sorting double n-d arrays across an arbitrary dimension in Scilab, as Matlab already does it (https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html). Currently Scilab only supports sorting 2d arrays  by lines or colums.